# how to add extra panel alongside default datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

i am trying to code a datepicker which will also show some information alongside the calendar.
currently i have this code.
http://jsfiddle.net/sFBn2/

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    insertMessage();
}
});

$('#ui-datepicker-div').delegate('.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next', 'click', insertMessage);

function insertMessage(message) {
    clearTimeout(insertMessage.timer);

if ($('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-calendar').is(':visible'))
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<div class="info">information panel</div>');
else
    insertMessage.timer = setTimeout(insertMessage, 10);
}
```

it shows "information panel" below the calendar. i want to display the info left side to the calendar. i guess i have to wrap the whole datepicker into a div, then insert panel and datepicker side by side. but not sure how to accomplish it.

**EDIT:**
navigating between months hides the panel. i think a better approach to the javascript is required.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `append()` to `prepend()` and changed your CSS to this:

```
.info{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -60px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
#ui-datepicker-div {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Not the cleanest solution (with negative margin), but it [**does work**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/sFBn2/1/).

Comment: yup panel does not seems to be part of the datepicker. but this was clever.

Comment: Change the `margin-left` of `#ui-datepicker-div` to `padding-left` and it fixes that problem. Check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/sFBn2/8/).

Comment: theirs one more bug. navigating between months hides the panel. i guess a better approach in js need to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EuBgE/135/)**

You just need to tweak some CSS to achieve this, Check the below codes

CSS

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    width: 400px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
table.ui-datepicker-calendar{
    width: 300px;
    float:right;
}
.ui-datepicker-header {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
.info{width:50px;height:50px;float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: urs is a good solution. but i guess if you look at the full screen result, there seems to be some problem with initial load of datepicker. also, there is dis thick line below the input box that appears because of my code. how to remove dat??

Comment: navigating between months hides the panel. how to fix dat.

Comment: See this fiddle, its working fine for jQuery version 1.6 but dont know whats happening with version 1.8 or greater, http://jsfiddle.net/EuBgE/135/